# Bash - Insert variables into string (command not found)

Tags: ssh, bash, shell

I try to write a script for get some software's version from many servers.
But I get this error message, when i try.

> bash: Postfix verzio:  MariaDB verzio:  OS verzio:  Java verzio: :
>   command not found
>
> bash: postfixverzio: command not found
>
> Null message body; hope that's ok

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

parancsok=$(<verziok_lekerdezese.sh)

while read line
do
    array=($line)
    echo "IP Addresses : ${array[0]} "
    ssh -t -t root@${array[0]} ${parancsok}
done < ipcimek_test.txt
```

Verziok_lekerdezese.sh:

```
postfixvr = $(postconf -d | grep -m 1 mail_version | cut -d= -f2)
mariadbvr = $(mysql -v)
osvr = $(cat /etc/redhat-release)
javavr = $(java -version)
hostname = $(cat /etc/hostname)

body = "Postfix verzio: $postfixvr MariaDB verzio: $mariadbvr OS verzio: $osvr Java verzio: $javavr"

echo $body | mail -s "Verziok - Szervernev: $hostname" sample@sample.com

exit
```

I apologize for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces on both sides of equal char `=` (in the assignment statements) in your bash script. So, the lines:

```
postfixvr = $(postconf -d | grep -m 1 mail_version | cut -d= -f2)
mariadbvr = $(mysql -v)
osvr = $(cat /etc/redhat-release)
javavr = $(java -version)
hostname = $(cat /etc/hostname)
```

should be written as:

```
postfixvr=$(postconf -d | grep -m 1 mail_version | cut -d= -f2)
mariadbvr=$(mysql -v)
osvr=$(cat /etc/redhat-release)
javavr=$(java -version)
hostname=$(cat /etc/hostname)
```

This applies to all assignments including `body =` also.

Comment: OMG, not every hero wears a cape.
I am very grateful, thank you.

Comment: BTW, while you cannot put spaces around the `=` in an assignment, you *must* use them in a comparison (e.g. `if [ $a=$b ]` does not do what you think it does). Also, there are a number of other problems with your script, such as variable references that aren't wrapped in double-quotes. [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) will point out many of them.